# Can't call function in different class, error: Cannot invoke with my parameter type

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have one class called GameScene which contains the following relevant code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    function grav(pos: CGPoint) -> CGVector {
        var direction = CGVector(dx: self.frame.width/2 - pos.x, dy: self.frame.height/2 - pos.y)
    direction = normalize(direction)
    let d = distance(pos, pos2: CGVector(dx: self.frame.width/2, dy: self.frame.height/2))
    direction = multiply(direction,scalar: mass/(d*d))
    return direction
   }
}
```

And another class called Player, where I try and call the grav method

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    function drawBall() {
        var gravity = GameScene.grav(self.position)
    }
}
```

However, I get the error: Cannot invoke 'grav' with an argument list of type '(CGPoint)'. When I let XCode autocomplete the method I get GameScene.grav(GameScene).  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grav` is an instance method. You are calling it on the class while you should call it on an **instance** of the class.